# Embed most recent YouTube videos on website?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I am currently learning web development and I am friends with someone that is fairly large on YouTube, so I offered to create him a website for free in order to build my portfolio while I learn. I am looking to be able to embed his 8 most recent videos and am not sure how to do it.

I found the code below on SO but it is for YouTube Data API V2 so no longer works. I can't seem to find a similar way to do it with API v3. Cheers,

Oli.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>YouTube Recent Upload Thing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="static_video"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showVideo(response) {
            if(response.data && response.data.items) {
                var items = response.data.items;
                if(items.length>0) {
                    var item = items[0];
                    var videoid = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+item.id;
                    console.log("Latest ID: '"+videoid+"'");
                    var video = "<iframe width='420' height='315' src='"+videoid+"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"; 
                    $('#static_video').html(video);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/urusernamehere/uploads?max-results=1&orderby=published&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=showVideo"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine if you make some adjustments.

First, to get the last 8 videos, you need to include that number in your 'query url' as `max-results`:

```
                                                                 here
                                                                   ▼
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/VEVO/uploads?max-results=8&orderby=published&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=showVideo
```

Then, to show every video, instead of an `if` statement, you need to have a loop (`for` loop here), and to `.append()` each video instead of replacing the entire content each time with `.html()`:

```
function showVideo(response) {
    if(response.data && response.data.items) {
        var items = response.data.items;
        // the loop i'm talking about
        for(var i=0, l=items.length; i<l; i++){
            var item = items[i];
            var videoid = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+item.id;
            console.log("Latest ID: '"+videoid+"'");
            var video = "<iframe width='420' height='315' src='"+videoid+"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
            // here, add the video to the container
            $('#static_video').append(video);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to add each video into seperate divs with ID's of '#static_video_0', '#static_video_1' etc. I've added `var divid = '#static_video_' + item;` and changed the ID to `$(divid)`. It's the only way I could think to do it but it doesn't work. Is there another way?

Comment: Sorry, I was being stupid. Should have been `'#static_video_' + i;`.

Comment: @Perceptic You got it :) **Edit**: If you have separate containers, you can stick with `.html()`, as you won't be overwriting any existing iframe. But `.append()` will work fine too.

Answer (score 1):

This will embed your "uploads" playlist. If you want your most recent video to play, just go to your channel and sort your uploads by most recent. Here's the code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=UUB8OUG89o0QWqmJ2lfzdyIg" seamless allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

`UUB8OUG89o0QWqmJ2lfzdyIg` is the unique id of my personal uploads playlist. To get the unique id of your playlist, take your unique channel id and simply change the `C` to a `U`.

```
UCB8OUG89o0QWqmJ2lfzdyIg // channel id
UUB8OUG89o0QWqmJ2lfzdyIg // uploads playlist id
```

All the Youtube playlists have ids, you just need to find them. You can alternatively find a playlist id by playing the full playlist with the "Play All" button. This will play the entire playlist on Youtube and you can copy the id out of the page url.