# Youtube Script Delay

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have a script that will pull the latest video from a youtube channel and embed it to my school page. It works but there are two issues.

One it doesn't immediately identify a recently posted video. Is there a delay from youtube before it syncs and the new posts can register?

Two the script runs but it does stop other video content on the page from displaying. Any idea why that might be?

I've looked it over and over and exhausted any searches I could think of.

Thanks for the help! Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="youtube_video" width="400" height="215"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script>
  var channelID = "UC0gcWgeEVOE7TDEKtLNnSuA";
  $.getJSON('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Ffeeds%2Fvideos.xml%3Fchannel_id%3D'+channelID, function(data) {
    var link = data.items[0].link;
    var id = link.substr(link.indexOf("=")+1);
    $("#youtube_video").attr("src","https://youtube.com/embed/"+id + "?controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% clear on what you are trying to achieve - but if you are trying to display MORE than 1 video, you currently only have a single #youtube_video element.  Rather you would likely need to create an element for each index of the data array and create unique IDs such as 
`#youtube_video + link[i]`

here's a Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/e620tuy8/

```
var channelID = "UC0gcWgeEVOE7TDEKtLNnSuA";
$.getJSON('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Ffeeds%2Fvideos.xml%3Fchannel_id%3D' + channelID, function(data) {
  var container = $('.container');
  for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
    var link = data.items[i].link;
    var id = link.substr(link.indexOf("=") + 1);
    var iframe = '<iframe id="youtube_video_id_' + i + '" src="https://youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0" width="400" height="215" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    container.append(iframe)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I DO want only the one video to show. The issue is that it's not the newest video that plays. I am not sure if there is a delay between when a video uploads to youtube and the script can detect it. Eventually the newest video will work but only after it's been uploaded for a few hours. Please let me know if that is more clear. Thanks again.

Comment: In the fiddle you sent included there are TWO new videos that have been uploaded two and one hour ago in the channel but they are not included when the script pulls the videos. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found, the answer with a little more digging.

Thanks to Frank's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43873099/5943182

Thank you to anyone who viewed.

I still don't know why the most recent wasn't being pulled in the above code, but the alternative method works wonderfully for me.